# How to force user to insert only numbers in a string if I force the first and the last to be letters in a 10 length string? Example S2351566A

Tags: c

```
Int char10];// length of string 
{
   if (!isalpha(str[0]) || !isalpha(str[8]))// force 1st and last array to be alphabet
    { 
        printf("invalid input\n"); exit(1); // invalid 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show it to us. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You cannot force the user to enter integers.You can only request him and later check whether user complied or not.

Comment: Yes I mean to check for a specific array for integers in a string?

Comment: The custom practice for fail-safe console input is to always use `fgets()` and read the input as a string. You can then sanity-check the input and block invalid data. Once you have verified that the input is ok, you can convert it to integer or whatever data type you like.

Answer (score 0):

if only 1st and last elements must be characters , then u can try this,
but if u want 1st and last element to be char and all middle to be digits then add another if statement after first "if"

boolean b=false;

while(b!=true){

take input in ch[10];

if(ch[0]>='A'&&ch[0]<='Z' && ch[9]>='A'&&ch[0]<='9'){

//means 1st and last are char

b=true;//will break because of this
}

else {

print f("Wrong input, enter again");

b=false;}

}
//this will run until user does not give correct input

Comment: I not sure can I check if boolean for c programming?

Comment: this code is for only 1st and last char to be alphabets, if u want the complete code (1st and last must be alphabets and all middle must be digits), I can provide you , well that is simple enough you can try first

Comment: Ok I give it a try first